# UITableView not working. Why?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I have a UITableViewController and I have specified the index titles so that the user can skip to specific letters much like the iPod app (the song list, specifically) on an iPhone. I have set up everything and implemented all the methods in the UITableViewProtocol.

Now, here is the problem. When I click an index on the right side (they are letters), the Table does not update properly. The top of it does update with the title I click on, but the actual rows do not. Why would this be happening? What method would I need to check? I find it weird that the title changes by the row content stays the same.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include some sample code so we can see what you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting up your dataSource as a two dimensional array?  The indexes on the right will sort by the outside index.

Check out Apple's explanation on how to populate an indexed table.  If you follow their code sample you should be able to get it to work.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Comment: +1 http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW30